# Windows Phone 7 (Zune) and iPhone (iTunes) on the same machine (Win7)

Tags: itunes, iphone, zune, windows-phone

I currently have an iPhone but was thinking about migrating to the new Windows Phone 7. I have had an iPhone for a long time now and I've invested a lot of time and money into my iTunes music collection (10k+ songs) so I'm curious as to how Windows Phone 7 & Zune will work if I bring it into the equation.

I will be giving the iPhone to the Mrs, so I will need iTunes to remain on the computer. And besides, I quite like iTunes and the iTunes store and I can't see that changing anytime soon. But any comments on the Zune software and how it compares to iTunes would be good.

But the real question is, if I invest in a Windows Phone 7, how easy is it sync all my iTunes music with the new phone? Will I have to install Zune and import all my iTunes music into it? Is that easy enough? Once both are installed and being used, do they play nicely together?

Comment: I have both an Ipod touch and a Zune at home.  Haven't seen if the protected music from iTunes will work on zune... will try tonight and let you know if no one answers by then.

Comment: They should. Songs purchased on iTunes aren't DRM'd to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Songs purchased on itunes since sometime in 2009 (not exactly sure when) are drm free, but any songs purchased before the switch still have the drm. I don't have any personal experience with this, but I have a friend who switched from iPod and dumbphone to Android and his music collection has been crippled because of his old DRM'd songs purchased from iTunes. I'm fairly certain any songs purchased from iTunes in early 2009 and before will not play nice with Zune/windows phone 7.

Comment: @roviuser Yeah, that was the case but when iTunes went DRM free there was an option to upgrade all your previously purchased music to DRM free versions - which I have done. See here: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-10132759-37.html

Comment: @Sathya iTunes music can be DRM'd but they can also be purchased DRM free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have a iPod touch 3rd gen and a Zune 3rd gen.  In order to sync the Zune you **must** use the Zune software and in order to sync with the iPod you **must** use iTunes.  *(There is however a way around this by using either winamp or mediamonkey to sync both devices, but this is kinda buggy).*  However using the Zune software to sync with the Zune songs that have been purchased on iTunes does work, and vice versa with the iPod touch and Zune purchased media.  I have personally checked this out with my two devices.  Assuming then that your future Windows Phone 7 works the same as my Zune, and your iPhone works the same as my iPod touch (duh) then you should have the same success.

What I have done is set the root folders of both iTunes and Zune to be the same.  They each pick up on the changes and things have generally worked out.  If however you aren't able to sync from either of the software there is the tedious task of burning the songs to a disk and then "re-ripping" the songs back onto the PC DRM free.

Comment: Cool - thanks for that, I think you've answered my question. Just out of interest, what are your thoughts on the iTunes vs Zune as software to play your music and maintain your music library?

Comment: @Charlino... Personally (and this is good that you didn't ask this in the actual question as this is VERY subjective) I like the gui of Zune, but the management of iTunes.

Comment: @Charlino: I personally love the Zune software, it seems faster than iTunes...It manages multiple devices well...